# Space of finite signed measures of total variation $\leq 1$ is the dual of something?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

I'm interested in the space $M$ of finite signed measures $\mu$ on some space $X$ with total variation $\Vert \mu \Vert \leq 1$. Assuming $X$ is nice enough (Hausdorff, metric, locally compact, second-countable, whatever you need), can I view $M$ as the dual of some nice space? Secondly, how nice is the weak* topology on $M$? Is it metric, etc.?

Comment: I would bet that $M$ is the unit ball of $C^\star_\infty(X)$, where $C_\infty$ means the functions that vanish at infinity on $X$.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you mean $\Vert\mu\Vert<\infty$? Otherwise $M$ is not a vector space (multiplying by a large scalar will destroy $\Vert\mu\Vert\le 1$. If you mean $\Vert\mu\Vert<\infty$, then yes, $M$ is the dual of the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity

Comment: I guess what I meant was is $M$ a nice subset of the dual of a nice space. So if what you say is correct, is it also true then that $M$ is the set of $\mu$ with $\int f d\mu \leq 1$ for all $f \in C_0$? And in this case can we take say the same for $f \in C_b$?

Comment: This is the content of the [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem)